# Finding avg statements in loop, like Big O, O(n), etc

Tags: java, methods, big-o

I'm so close I can taste it! I am to count all the statements in my method and find take the average number of statements for some value "n." So i believe I have everything set up correctly as far as my statement counters, but I am not sure how to count this loop in a way that I can take the average for each "n." I believe I have to divide my total statements by something, but I am unsure what that number is- can someone point me in the right direction? I know I am supposed to eventually get a quadratic fxn, O(n^2)...

Here is the method I am evaluating...

```
public static int myMethod(int[] array) {
    int statements = 0;
    for (int next = 1; next < array.length; next++) {
        statements++;
        int val = array[next];
        int index = next;
        while (index > 0 && val < array[index - 1]) {
            statements++;
            array[index] = array[index - 1];
            index--;
        }
        array[index] = val;
    }
    return statements;
}
```

}

And here is my test class that calls the method...

```
statements = myClass.myMethod(array); //this is the call we want to measure
                     //I believe the statements variable is working correctly.
        avgStatements = statements/(something here?)
```

EDIT: I should probably mention what the method does... it takes an integer, say 5, and from a random order it arranges the 1 through 5 in ascending order, for instance if it was 5, we could have 4 1 2 3 5, and it would organize it in an array, 1 2 3 4 5.... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure what you are trying to calculate, but if I guess correctly, n would be the size of the array (`array.length`) and you are required to calculate the average number of statements per each member of the array.

Therefore

```
 avgStatements = statements/array.length
```

But if you want to count all the statements, you should notice that the inner loop has two statements (not counting the statements++), while the outer loop has three statements.

Therefore you should probably count like this :

```
public static int myMethod(int[] array) {
    int statements = 0;
    for (int next = 1; next < array.length; next++) {
        statements+=3;
        int val = array[next];
        int index = next;
        while (index > 0 && val < array[index - 1]) {
            statements+=2;
            array[index] = array[index - 1];
            index--;
        }
        array[index] = val;
    }
    return statements;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so we have statements +=3 because 'int val...' 'int index...' and 'while()' are all 3 statements executing in that loop? And then the same theory for inside the while loop?

Comment: Quick note here, my average statements seems to be forming a linear function, when I was expecting it to be quadratic, I was expecting the values to increase quite a bit faster for my avgStatements variable.

Comment: @Consuela The `while` is not counter as one of the three (since the inner loop is counted separately). The third is `array[index] = val`.

Comment: @Consuela In order for this code to be linear in relation to the length to the array, statements/array.length should be constant.

Comment: @Consuela If it's quadratic, statements/(array.length*array.length) would be constant.

Comment: So how do I go about making this quadratic? changing my avgStatements equation? Or do I just accept it as linear?

Comment: statements/(array.length*array.length) = 0 regardless of the input

Comment: @Consuela Try to calculate the average with floats instead of ints, since the average can be < 1. 0.5*n^2 or 0.25*n^2 are still quadratic.

Comment: okay, in this case as n increases, I seem to be getting a smaller output, from 10 being ~.8 to 5000 being ~.49

Comment: @Consuela Try larger n's, to see if it converges.

Comment: I think it does, I tried 100k, seems to converge around .49, does that mean we have log(n)?

Comment: @Consuela What did you compute? statements/(array.length*array.length)? If that's why you computed, it means O(n^2) (since statements/n^2 is constant).

Comment: Yes that is what I computed for my avg. So when I am graphing this equation I want to use statements/array.length? because I want to see a growth fxn?

Comment: @Consuela That depends on what you wish to show in your graph. `statements/array.length` would give you a graph that behaves like the function f(n)=0.49*n, which means that for each element of the array, you perform 0.49*n operations in average.

Comment: I just want to make a function showing n values as my x, and the average number of statements executed for my y, I was really hoping this fxn would look quadratic.

Comment: @Consuela It would look quadratic if instead of calculating an average, you simply plot the number of statements for each array.length (without dividing by anything). Your function would look like f(n)=0.49*n^2.

Comment: Yeah it does, but I must use the average number of statements as my output for each n value, and it should theoretically be increasing, but it's fine, it is what it is, so my average number of statements is statements/(array.length*array.length)? you've been great btw thanks